# Apex Bulkification -- Too many SOQL queries: 101

Tags: apex, process-builder, bulkification, bulk

I have an APEX Class that I have bulkified but is still giving me trouble with Batches of 200 Records. I was hoping to get assistance in making the APEX more efficient, any assistance/direction would be greatly appreciated.

I have a process Builder that Fires an Apex Class on the Lead Object when one of the following is met:

```
        ISCHANGED([Lead].MobilePhone),
        ISCHANGED([Lead].Phone),
        ISCHANGED([Lead].Home_Phone__c),
        ISCHANGED([Lead].Alternate_Phone__c),
        ISCHANGED([Lead].Alternate_Phone_2__c),
        ISNEW()
```

The Process Builder Passes the [Lead].Id to the APEX Class.

```
public class UpdatePhoneTrimFields {

    @InvocableMethod
    public static void invocableTrimPhoneNumbers(List<String> ids){

        String objectType = ids[0];

        if(objectType.startsWithIgnoreCase('00Q')){

            updateBulkifiedLeadPhoneTrimFields(ids); 
        }
        else if(objectType.startsWithIgnoreCase('003')){

            updateBulkifiedContactPhoneTrimFields(ids);
        } 
        else if(objectType.startsWithIgnoreCase('001')){

            updateBulkifiedAccountPhoneTrimFields(ids);
        } 
        else {

            system.debug('Unknown Record Type - Cannot Proceed');
        }

    }

    private static Decimal normalizePhoneNumber(String rawPhoneNumber){
        try{
            if(rawPhoneNumber != null){
                return Decimal.ValueOf(rawPhoneNumber.replaceAll('[^0-9]', ''));
            }
        } catch (Exception e){

            System.debug('An Unexpected error occurred trimming a phone number: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static void updateBulkifiedLeadPhoneTrimFields(List<String> ids){
        
        system.debug('Attempting to Normalize the Phone numbers for a list of ' + ids.size() + ' leads.');

        list<Lead> leadsToUpdate = new List<lead>(); 

        for(Id recordId: ids){
            
            String stringRecordId = Id.ValueOf(recordId);

            if(stringRecordId.startsWithIgnoreCase('00Q')){
                try {
                    Lead l = [SELECT Phone, MobilePhone, Home_Phone__c, Alternate_Phone__c, Alternate_Phone_2__c, Phone_Trim__c, MobilePhone_Trim__c, Home_Phone_Trim__c, Alternate_Phone_Trim__c, Alternate_Phone_2_Trim__c FROM Lead WHERE Id =: recordId];

                    l.Phone_Trim__c = UpdatePhoneTrimFields.normalizePhoneNumber(l.Phone);
                    l.MobilePhone_Trim__c = UpdatePhoneTrimFields.normalizePhoneNumber(l.MobilePhone);
                    l.Home_Phone_Trim__c = UpdatePhoneTrimFields.normalizePhoneNumber(l.Home_Phone__c);
                    l.Alternate_Phone_Trim__c = UpdatePhoneTrimFields.normalizePhoneNumber(l.Alternate_Phone__c);
                    l.Alternate_Phone_2_Trim__c = UpdatePhoneTrimFields.normalizePhoneNumber(l.Alternate_Phone_2__c);

                    system.debug('Adding Lead to List to Normalize: '+ l);
                    leadsToUpdate.add(l);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.debug('An Unexpected error occurred normalizing Lead Phone Fields: ' + e.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                System.debug('Cannot Normalize Phone for this record: ' + recordId + '. Not a Lead');
            }   
        }

        try {
            system.debug('Updading a list of Leads with ' + leadsToUpdate.size() + ' records');
            system.debug(leadsToUpdate);
            update leadsToUpdate; 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('An Unexpected error occurred normalizing Lead Phone Fields: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void updateBulkifiedContactPhoneTrimFields(List<String> ids){

        system.debug('Attempting to Normalize the Phone numbers for a list of ' + ids.size() + ' Contacts.');

        list<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();

        for(Id recordId: ids){

            String stringRecordId = Id.ValueOf(recordId);

            if(stringRecordId.startsWithIgnoreCase('003')){
                try{
                    Contact c = [SELECT Phone, MobilePhone, HomePhone, OtherPhone, Phone_Trim__c, MobilePhone_Trim__c, HomePhone_Trim__c, OtherPhone_Trim__c FROM Contact Where Id =: recordId];

                    c.Phone_Trim__c = UpdatePhoneTrimFields.normalizePhoneNumber(c.Phone);
                    c.MobilePhone_Trim__c = UpdatePhoneTrimFields.normalizePhoneNumber(c.MobilePhone);  
                    c.HomePhone_Trim__c = UpdatePhoneTrimFields.normalizePhoneNumber(c.HomePhone);
                    c.OtherPhone_Trim__c = UpdatePhoneTrimFields.normalizePhoneNumber(c.OtherPhone);

                    system.debug('Adding Contact to List to Normalize: '+ c);
                    contactsToUpdate.add(c);

                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.debug('An Unexpected error occurred normalizing Lead Phone Fields: ' + e.getMessage());
                }
            }else {
                System.debug('Cannot Normalize Phone for this record: ' + recordId + '. Not a Contact');
            }
        }

        try {
            system.debug('Updating List of Contacts with ' + contactsToUpdate.size() + ' records');
            system.debug(contactsToUpdate);
            update contactsToUpdate;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('An Unexpected error occurred trimming Contact Phone Fields: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void updateBulkifiedAccountPhoneTrimFields(List<String> ids){

        system.debug('Attempting to Normalize the Phone numbers for a list of ' + ids.size() + ' Accounts.');

        list<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();

        for(Id recordId: ids){

            String stringRecordId = Id.ValueOf(recordId);

            if(stringRecordId.startsWithIgnoreCase('001')){
                try{
                    Account a = [SELECT Phone, Alternate_Phone__c, Alternate_Phone_2__c, Phone_Trim__c, Alternate_Phone_Trim__c, Alternate_Phone_2_Trim__c FROM Account WHERE Id =: recordId];
            
                    a.Phone_Trim__c = UpdatePhoneTrimFields.normalizePhoneNumber(a.Phone);
                    a.Alternate_Phone_Trim__c = UpdatePhoneTrimFields.normalizePhoneNumber(a.Alternate_Phone__c);
                    a.Alternate_Phone_2_Trim__c = UpdatePhoneTrimFields.normalizePhoneNumber(a.Alternate_Phone_2__c);
            
                    system.debug('Adding Account to List to Normalize: '+ a);
                    accountsToUpdate.add(a);
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    System.debug('An Unexpected error occurred normalizing Account Phone Fields: ' + e.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                System.debug('Cannot Normalize Phone for this record: ' + recordId + '. Not an Account');
            }
        }

        try {
            system.debug('Updating List of Accounts with ' + accountsToUpdate.size() + ' records');
            system.debug(accountsToUpdate);
            update accountsToUpdate;
        } catch (Exception e)   {
            System.debug('An Unexpected error occurred trimming Account Phone Fields: ' + e.getMessage());
        }      
    }

}
```

1. This Apex Class can be fired from three process builders related to the Lead/Account/Contact Object. So the Process builder calls an @invocablemethod that determines the Object Type. Based on the Object Type it will then call a private method.
2. This Private Method is updateBulkifiedLeadPhoneTrimFields. It loops through the array/list of records - looks up the appropriate information updates the record and pushes it to a new array. Once the Loop is done we update the list of records together.
3. The updates that are being done are the same across all of the methods - this updates to the phonetrim fields (normalize the phone fields). The Method Called is normalizePhoneNumber

**updateBulkifiedLeadPhoneTrimFields**

```
private static void updateBulkifiedLeadPhoneTrimFields(List<String> ids){

        system.debug('Attempting to Normalize the Phone numbers for a list of ' + ids.size() + ' leads.');

        list<Lead> leadsToUpdate = new List<lead>(); 

        for(Id recordId: ids){

            String stringRecordId = Id.ValueOf(recordId);

            if(stringRecordId.startsWithIgnoreCase('00Q')){
                try {
                    Lead l = [SELECT Phone, MobilePhone, Home_Phone__c, Alternate_Phone__c, Alternate_Phone_2__c, Phone_Trim__c, MobilePhone_Trim__c, Home_Phone_Trim__c, Alternate_Phone_Trim__c, Alternate_Phone_2_Trim__c FROM Lead WHERE Id =: recordId];

                    l.Phone_Trim__c = UpdatePhoneTrimFields.normalizePhoneNumber(l.Phone);
                    l.MobilePhone_Trim__c = UpdatePhoneTrimFields.normalizePhoneNumber(l.MobilePhone);
                    l.Home_Phone_Trim__c = UpdatePhoneTrimFields.normalizePhoneNumber(l.Home_Phone__c);
                    l.Alternate_Phone_Trim__c = UpdatePhoneTrimFields.normalizePhoneNumber(l.Alternate_Phone__c);
                    l.Alternate_Phone_2_Trim__c = UpdatePhoneTrimFields.normalizePhoneNumber(l.Alternate_Phone_2__c);

                    system.debug('Adding Lead to List to Normalize: '+ l);
                    leadsToUpdate.add(l);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.debug('An Unexpected error occurred normalizing Lead Phone Fields: ' + e.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                System.debug('Cannot Normalize Phone for this record: ' + recordId + '. Not a Lead');
            }   
        }

        try {
            system.debug('Updading a list of Leads with ' + leadsToUpdate.size() + ' records');
            system.debug(leadsToUpdate);
            update leadsToUpdate; 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('An Unexpected error occurred normalizing Lead Phone Fields: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**normalizePhoneNumber**

```
    private static Decimal normalizePhoneNumber(String rawPhoneNumber){
        try{
            if(rawPhoneNumber != null){
                return Decimal.ValueOf(rawPhoneNumber.replaceAll('[^0-9]', ''));
            }
        } catch (Exception e){

            System.debug('An Unexpected error occurred trimming a phone number: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When running in Batches of 200 I am receiving the following error:
`An Apex error occurred: System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101 ---`

**Question(s)**

1. Is there a way I can make this more efficient? If So, How? My ultimate goal would be to have this be able to run in batches of 200 records.

**Update**

I made the following change and it looks to have worked. Any recommendations on any further updates?

```
        
        system.debug('Attempting to Normalize the Phone numbers for a list of ' + ids.size() + ' leads.');

            List<Lead> leadsToUpdate = [SELECT Id, Phone, MobilePhone, Home_Phone__c, Alternate_Phone__c, Alternate_Phone_2__c, Phone_Trim__c, MobilePhone_Trim__c, Home_Phone_Trim__c, Alternate_Phone_Trim__c, Alternate_Phone_2_Trim__c FROM Lead WHERE Id =: ids]; 

            for(Lead l: leadsToUpdate){
                try{
                    l.Phone_Trim__c = UpdatePhoneTrimFields.normalizePhoneNumber(l.Phone);
                    l.MobilePhone_Trim__c = UpdatePhoneTrimFields.normalizePhoneNumber(l.MobilePhone);
                    l.Home_Phone_Trim__c = UpdatePhoneTrimFields.normalizePhoneNumber(l.Home_Phone__c);
                    l.Alternate_Phone_Trim__c = UpdatePhoneTrimFields.normalizePhoneNumber(l.Alternate_Phone__c);
                    l.Alternate_Phone_2_Trim__c = UpdatePhoneTrimFields.normalizePhoneNumber(l.Alternate_Phone_2__c);
                } catch(Exception e){
                    System.debug('An Unexpected error occurred normalizing Lead with Id: ' + l.Id + '. Error' + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            system.debug('Updading a list of Leads with ' + leadsToUpdate.size() + ' records');
            system.debug(leadsToUpdate);
            update leadsToUpdate; 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you have queries inside of a loop.

In your attempt at bulkification, we see this

```java
for(Id recordId: ids){
    String stringRecordId = Id.ValueOf(recordId);

    if(stringRecordId.startsWithIgnoreCase('00Q')){
        try {
            // This query is inside of a loop
            // That's a problem
            Lead l = [SELECT Phone, MobilePhone, Home_Phone__c, Alternate_Phone__c, Alternate_Phone_2__c, Phone_Trim__c, MobilePhone_Trim__c, Home_Phone_Trim__c, Alternate_Phone_Trim__c, Alternate_Phone_2_Trim__c FROM Lead WHERE Id =: recordId];
   // ...
```

Since you only have a single filter in your query, it's easy to pull out of the loop using the standard iterate-gather-query approach.

```java
// First, set up a collection to hold the data you want to query against
Set<Id> recordIds = new Set<Id>();

// Iterate over your records to gather the data
for(SomeObject__c someObj :trigger.new){
    // gather your data
    recordIds.add(someObj.Relationship_Field__c);
}

// Query and store for later use
Map<Id, SObject> sobjMap = new Map<Id, SObject>([SELECT Id, Field1__c, Field2__c FROM OtherObject__c WHERE Id IN :recordIds);

// Iterate over the records again
// This time, you can pull the related data from the map you made earlier
for(SomeObject__c someObj :trigger.new){
    OtherObject__c relatedRecord = sobjMap.get(someObj.Relationship_Field__c);

    // do other work
}
```

You probably don't need to go through that much trouble though, since you're only working with 1 SObject at a time, there shouldn't be anything stopping you from just simply feeding a for loop with a query that uses your `ids` list directly.

```java
for(Lead myLead :[SELECT Id, Field2__c, Field3__c FROM Lead WHERE Id IN :ids]){
    // do work
}
```

Other than that...

- you may consider using the `getSObjectType()` method of the `Id` class to make your SObject detection more readable

  - e.g. `SObjectType sobjType = ((Id)ids[0]).getSObjectType();` and `if(sobjType == Lead.SObjectType)`
- Swallowing exceptions is generally a bad thing. It makes it harder to detect when you have an issue, and makes it harder to debug the issue once you know you have one. Consider eliminating *all* of your try/catch statements